# File.ReadAllBytes throws The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, file-io

I am first calling Process.Start with process that pipes to a file i.e. `"cmd /c \"myProc.exe\" > out.txt"`. Then I am trying to read that file using ReadAllBytes. I don't use RedirectOutput due to different problems. Now, I hit `IOException "The process cannot access the file..."`. Of course I am doing `Process.WaitForExit()`. I tried to create some retry logic, but even with 10s retry some of the files still stay locked.

Any idea who is locking the file and how to make this more robust.

Comment: You could use the SysInterals tools to check who's locking the file? Who writes the file? `myProc.exe`? In that case you could make it so that `myProc.exe` doesn't require an exclusive lock on the file? Or does `myProc.exe` try to read the file? Then which application creates the file and are you sure this application doesn't require an exclusive lock?

Comment: `I don't use RedirectOutput due to different problems` Reconsider it. A process writing to a file, another one reading the same file is not a good solution.

Comment: My proc is terminated after WaitForExit() so concurrency really shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @L.B. Yes, I would like to use RedirectOutput. The problem is stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226578/reading-process-output-that-contains-mixed-encoding. If you have any ideas how to solve this please help :)

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (read, text, file, bytes) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!